# proc report control the observation

Tags: sas, report, proc

```
data new ;
 var1 = "Please post a sample data and criteria for the break and wanted output." ;
 output ;
 var1 = "Have you tried using proc report - if positive, post your code and output" ;
 output ;
run;
```

I want to control the observation like I need "*Please post a sample data and criteria for the break and*" in the first line and "*wanted output.*" in the second line using proc report.

I've tried writing proc report but I am not sure why I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline styling directives, such as `^{newline 1}`.

```
data have;
 var1 = "Please post a sample data and criteria for the break and ^{NEWLINE 1}wanted output." ;
 output ;
 var1 = "Have you tried using proc report - if positive, post your code and output" ;
 output ;
run;

ods escapechar='^';
ods listing close;
ods html;

proc report data=have;  
run;

ods html;
```

[image]